# Is there a good notation for "ratio" comparable to the use of $\Delta$ for "difference"?

Tags: calculus, algebra, notation, precalculus

It is standard to use the symbol $\Delta$ to indicate a change in a quantity between two points on a curve, two rows on a table, and so forth.  For linear functions, we write slope = $\Delta y / \Delta x$; this notation is used all over the place in Physics and Chemistry.

But when looking at exponential functions, the quantity that relates naturally to $\Delta x = x_2-x_1$ is not $\Delta y = y_2 - y_1$, but rather  $\bf{\frac{y_2}{y_1}}$.  This suggests that it would be helpful to have some kind of notation to signify "multiplicative change," in analogy with using $\Delta$ to signify "additive change".

Is there such a symbol?  Is it used in any textbooks?

Comment: I have never seen $\Delta y = \frac{y_2}{y_1}$ used. Mind providing a reference? The usual $\Delta y = y_2 - y_1$ is the only one I see in math, physics, chemistry, engineering...

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I wrote (or I miswrote it).  My whole point is that $\Delta y$ means $y_2 - y_1$, and I'm wondering if there is an analogous (different) notation for $y_2/y_1$.

Comment: There is $\rho$ which is used more for variable density.  There are texts which use a multiplicative scale instead of an additive scale in considering alternative forms of the calculus.  I know of no widely accepted notation for the concept you consider.  Gerhard "Living In A Null-Measure Set" Paseman, 2015.05.04

Comment: Maybe they use $\Delta \log$ instead.

Comment: $\Delta \log$ would do the mathematical work I have in mind, but in terms of instructional sequencing it puts the cart before the horse.  I am thinking about the way in which one introduces exponential functions:  You look at a table of values in which $x$ increments by some uniform amount, and say "Look, every time $x$ goes up by such-and-such, corresponding $y$ value multiplies by such and such".  I was just thinking how odd it is that we can write "$\Delta x = 1$" to indicate that $x$ increases by $1$, but don't have an analogous way to indicate that $y$ increases by a constant multiplier.

Comment: ... and (to get back to my point) that notation would be useful when *first introducing* exponential functions, which is *before* logarithms are taught.  So $\Delta \log$ would be useful after the fact.

Comment: Great question and I intended to ask a similar one after having seen [this question on HSM:SE](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/2254/why-was-delta-delta-chosen-to-represent-change-of-a-quantity). I find it interesting that there is $\Pi$ for products, $\Sigma$ for sums, $\Delta$ for differences but apparently no sign for quotients.

Comment: Not that I know of, though Cajori's (2013) [**book**](https://books.google.com/books?id=_byqAAAAQBAJ&lpg=PP250&pg=PA250) (which I glanced through for an earlier - since migrated - query of JO'R's) has some nice historical information.

Comment: Honestly, I never understood the use of $\Delta$ for a difference of two real numbers. For starters, the result is just a real number; the use of a special symbol will lead more than one student to think it's something more. Also, if we accept that sometimes we want to make it clear that this real number comes from a difference, the original two numbers are quite lost anyways (we'd have to write something like $\Delta(x_1,x_2)$). All in all I think it only adds to the mystification of mathematical symbols.

Comment: I don't know on symbol either, but understand the desire. I do know that percentage growth is frequently of interest in business ("CAGR").  There are also decibal scales for problems in acoustics, explosives, etc. where what matters is the log scale property (symbol dB)

Answer (score 6):

I likewise have needed such a thing—to converse coherently about transformation properties (actually symmetries) of power, exponential, and logarithmic functions. I did not find anything in textbooks or anything commonly used otherwise. I considered using $\rho$ for "ratio", but settled on $\sigma$ (and  $\sigma_y$ as needed), because in conversing, "scaling" was more used than "ratio." Following are examples of summary statements.

An exponential function $f(x) = A b^x$ scales by the same factor over equal increments of the input. The base $b$ gives the factor over a unit increment.
The base to the power of an input increment $\Delta x$ gives the output factor: $$\sigma_y = b^{\Delta x}.$$
The graph is invariant under the family of transformations
$$(x,y) \rightarrow (x + \Delta, b^\Delta y)$$
where $\Delta$ can be any real number.

We use $\Delta x$, but "$\sigma y$" is clumsy, so I use a subscript. I try to avoid the subscript. I would write the transformation property ("equivariance") of the function as
$$f(x + \Delta) = b^\Delta f(x),$$
provided students were ready for such symbolic stuff. (Usually some are, some aren't—a chance to "differentiate" instruction.) In making tables of values, often a column would be labeled with a $\sigma_y$ (or $\sigma_x$ for logarithmic and power functions).

With exponential functions I mostly avoid this $\sigma_y$ notation. If we have the exercise of finding the parameters for an exponential curve going through $(1,6)$ and $(3,30)$, say, I would encourage putting the data in a table and writing $\Delta x = 2$ on the $x$ side and $b^2 = 5$ somewhere, just saying 5 is the output scaling associated to an input increment of 2, rather than writing $\sigma_y = 5$. Solve for the base, and go from there.

Answer (score 2):

I think its worth noting that the obelus symbol ($\div$) coincidentally looks like a vertical fraction and does denote division. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obelus

It could be used as a table header pretty easily:

$x \ \ \ y \ \ \div y$
$2 \ \ \ 7 \ \ $
$4 \ \  35 \ \ \ \ 5$

But could get confusing as an inline symbol: $\div y=5$ or  $\frac{\div y}{\div x}=5/2$ don't quite look right, and try saying "Ten times the y ratio": $10\div y$ We'd get confused .

Maybe $\div$ with a triangle or circle around it?  I don't know of a premade symbol like that though.